# Sql Get all songs having type work and having year greater than love song belonging to that Album

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having table called Album each having title song, SongList having each song belonging to particular album and SongDetails as below

**Album**

```
AlbumCode   TitleSong
A1           TS1
A2           TS2
```

**SongList**

```
SongCode    AlbumCode
TS1          A1
S2           A1
S3           A1
TS2          A2
S5           A2
```

**SongDetails**

```
id  Song    type          year  
1   TS1     love          2016  
2   S2      partialLove   2016  
3   TS1     partialLove   2016  
4   S3      work          2017
```

Question is : I need to get all songs having type work and having year greater than love song belonging to that Album. So in this case expected output would be
 `4 S3      work          2017`

I am struggling to join 3 tables but not able to get desired output 
This is what I tried until now, How to compare those 2 results in single query and get result which will give me list of songs

```
select * from Albums a join AlbumSongList asl ON a.AlbumCode = asl.AlbumCode
JOIN songManagement sm ON sm.Song=asl.SongCode WHERE sm.type = 'work'

select * from Albums a join AlbumSongList asl ON a.AlbumCode = asl.AlbumCode
JOIN songManagement sm ON sm.Song=asl.SongCode WHERE sm.type = 'love'
```

Comment: Do your own homework. Make an effort.

Comment: You've told us what you want to do, great, but what is your question? What is the problem you're having? What were ***your*** attempts and why didn't they work? What research did you do to solve your (homework?) question and what about the documentation you read didn't you understand?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is homework without an attempt at a solution

Comment: So, what's wrong with your results, @somegeek ? What is the result you're after?

Comment: @Larnu I need to get all songs having type work and having year greater than love song belonging to that Album, it is in the question. I would also appreciate if I get to know resources to improve sql query creation skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an `EXISTS` would serve the purpose here:

```
--Sample data
--We never actually use Albums
WITH Albums AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('A1','TS1'),
                ('A2','TS2'))V(AlbumCode,TitleSong)),
SongList AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('TS1','A1'),
                ('S2','A1'),
                ('S3','A1'),
                ('TS2','A2'),
                ('S5','A2'))V(SongCode, AlbumCode)),
SongDetails AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'TS1','love',2016),
                (2,'S2','partialLove',2016),
                (3,'TS1','partialLove',2016),
                (4,'S3','work',2017))V(id, Song, type, year))
--Solution
SELECT SDw.id,
       SDw.Song,
       SDw.type,
       SDw.year
FROM SongList SLw
     JOIN SongDetails SDw ON SLw.SongCode = SDw.Song
WHERE SDw.type = 'work'
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM SongList SLl
                   JOIN SongDetails SDl ON SLl.SongCode = SDl.Song
              WHERE SLl.AlbumCode = SLw.AlbumCode
                AND SDl.year < SDw.year
                AND SDl.type = 'love');
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I was thinking is this achievable without using Exists?